# Where is the keyboard profile file stored on my MacBook for VMware Fusion 8?

Tags: vmware

I am trying to add some keyboard shortcuts to VMware Fusion 8 but the dialog is kinda wonky:

[image: VMware Fusion 8 keyboard shortcut definition dialog]

Here the two dropdowns doesn't drop down, so any key I don't have on my MacBook is impossible to configure. For instance, I was trying to configure Cmd+Right to be the Windows End key, since I'm programming in Visual Studio I want quick keyboard navigation, however, since the dropdown doesn't drop down, it is impossible for me to pick the End key.

So, the configuration file that contains this keyboard profile, does anyone know where on my system this is stored so perhaps I can hack it directly in there?

Comment: Should be in: `/Users/$USER/Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion/preferences`

Comment: Yep, there it was and it contained the keyboard entries as well, if you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VMware Fusion's Application Preferences are saved on a per User basis in:

```
/Users/$USER/Library/Preferences/VMware Fusion/preferences
```